# I need to position image at the bottom of the background image and have them stay in place when window is resized

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a background image and I have other images that need to stay at the bottom of the background image, even if the window resizes or there is a different screen size.

This is a ReactJS web app so any javascript or CSS will work.

CSS:

```
html {
   background: url(imageInMemory.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: contain;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// I calculate the ratio for 'background-size: contain'
let A = window.innerWidth;
let B = window.innerHeight;
let W = naturalWidth; // Width of image, I have this hardcoded
let H = naturalHeight; // Height of image, I have this hardcoded
const ratio = Math.min((A/W), (B/H));// this is the ratio to which the image was scaled given the current window size.
// I position images on top of background images where they should be using this new ratio
<div style={{marginTop: ratio * H * .7}}>
    <img src='otherImage'/>
</div>
```

This works on some window sizes, but sometimes the images will not be on top of the right area of the background Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a responsive layout for one image behind and a floating form resizing and repositioning all fields and texts.
I will not put all my code here, then i said to you create your own code inside a function named like "update_field_positions" running in events window resize and load.

For screens with more than 608px the height of my image is 882px

Then i define the reason of proportion: img_cadastro.clientHeight / 882

And use this value for resize and reposition all the items

I used css too:

```
@media screen and (max-width:608px) {
        .img_cadastro {
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }
```

and

```
@media screen and (min-width:608px) {
    .img_cadastro {
        width:608px;
        height:882px;
    }
```

A little piece of my working js code:

```
function update_field_positions() {
    .... (some code) ....
    var razao = img_cadastro.clientHeight / 882;
    bloco_campos_ext.style.top = ((258 * razao) + compensador) + "px";
    div_voucher.style.marginTop = ((57 * razao) + compensador_voucher) + "px";
    div_voucher.style.marginLeft = ((120 * razao) + compensador) + "px";
    nome_voucher.style.fontSize = (24 * razao) + "px";
    cod_voucher.style.fontSize = (28 * razao) + "px";
    resize_object(bloco_campos_ext, 357, 148, razao, false);
    resize_object(bloco_campos_int, 357, 148, razao, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `css` to your `div`:

```
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
```

Comment: This does bot work because at a certain window width the bottom will be a margin, resulting on the images not being on the correct area of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

For a responsive screen working when the windows is resized

Your codes of getting ratio and repositioning should be inside a function, you could create a function named update_field_positions for example: update_field_positions()

then your function must be called in 2 events, onload and window.resize

example:

```
function start() {
    update_field_positions();
    window.onresize = update_field_positions;
}
<body onLoad="start()">
```

Tou should use onload, for wait objects become ready before working with them to avoid errors and window.onresize to update values with a new window.innerWidth

The other problem is that the window can be resized to a smaller size than your image

And then you have to create some code to handle these situations:

```
if (window.innerWidth < naturalWidth) {...}
```

Comment: @Molina12
This the responsive page i did
See, it's working, you can try analyse souce code js, css and html:

[link]http://www.p6mkt.com.br/promop6sjc/